# Is a pointer to a function which have unknown number of parameters possible?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I am writing a simple class to measure performance of a function in terms of time . The user should be able to send a pointer to his function, parameters of the function, times to call the function and i will call the function, return the time elapsed. Here my problem is I dont know how many parameters the user's function takes! I thought to use variadic functions to get unknown number of parameters, however I still have the problem of declaring the function pointer that user passes as a parameter(because it doesnt have constant variable number) and not knowing the types of variables I recieve by using a variadic function.

It should not be hard, i guess :) All i want to do is to call a function which is not defined by me by using a function pointer.

Is there any way to solve these problems or?

Comment: Removed C tag as the OP specified he was writing a class.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really make sense to have a function-pointer to a function with unknown arguments.  If you don't know how many arguments there are (let alone their types), how are you going to fill out the arguments at run-time?

The best you can do is require that the user's functions all have the same prototype, namely to take a `va_list` as a parameter, and require that your library provide your library with that same `va_list` (see also http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html).

e.g.:

```
// Function-pointer type
typedef void (*func_t)(int, va_list);

// Your timer library function
void timer(func_t *p_func, ...)
{   
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, fmt);
    p_func(0, arg);
    va_end(arg);
}


// User's function
void user_function(int first_arg, va_list args)
{
   ...
};

// Invoke the timer library function
timer(&user_function, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Comment: That _does_ make sense. You know exactly how many arguments to call the function with, only it's a different number (and different types) for different functions you want to measure.

Comment: @sbi: Right, but there's no meaningful way that you could do that programatically.  Your only option is to transparently forward a `va_list`.

Comment: @Oli: There is a way. See my answer.

Comment: Ah that seems like what i need :) Thanks a lot everyone ^^ By the way the link you posted looks familiar... I am sure i had a look at it today while searching for an answer :)

Comment: @sbi: Yes, I imagine your method works (although I've never tried using lambdas in C++), and it's avoiding the "passing variable number of arguments" entirely (which I still contend is not a meaningful concept!).  I guess the only question is whether the OP's compiler supports it!

Comment: @Oli: With GCC and VC supporting, it's very likely the OP can use this. If not, Mikael has posted an answer using `boost::bind` (which amounts to the same as a lambda function, though without compiler support). Both are much better than functions with variable number of arguments, because they don't forgo compile-time check. (If I call your `timer()` function with the wrong types/number of arguments, the compiler will happily compile the code, but all hell might break lose at runtime. I have learned to prefer compile-time checks. A bug found by compiling won't blow up into a customer's face.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth C has variadic function pointers including an elipsis, like `void (*funPointer)(char*, ...);` Does C++ not support this?

Comment: @BrianGordon: I would assume that C++ also has variadic function pointers.  But the point I'm making above is that a variadic function is not the same as an arbitrary function with unknown arguments.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks for your answer, is your solution usable in C? and what is "fmt" in the va_start?

Answer (score 3):

I think ***lambda functions*** can be used to do this:

```
template< typename Func >
unsigned int measure(Func f)
{
  // take time
  f();
  // take time
  return result;
}

void test_func_1(int i)            { std::cout << i; }
void test_func_2(std::ostream& os) { os << 42; }

int main()
{
  auto lambda_func_1 = [](){ test_func_1(42); };
  const unsigned int time_1 = measure( lambda_func_1 );
  std::cout << "calling test_func_1(42) took " << time_1 << " <unit>\n";

  auto lambda_func_2 = [](){ test_func_2(std::cerr); };
  const unsigned int time_2 = measure( lambda_func_2 );
  std::cout << "calling test_func_2(std::cout) took " << time_2 << " <unit>\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Of course, lambda functions will be part of C++ only after the next standard is released (hopefully this year), but quite a few compilers (among them GCC and VC) already implement them, so you have a chance to do it this way.

---

One might also make a function template employing variadic template arguments and perfect forwarding, passing the arguments of the function to be measured to the measuring function, which then passes them on. But I haven't played with this, so I can't write this up.

Comment: I will also give this a try. The measure( [](){test_func(42);] ); function call seems a bit confusing but probably that is because of I dont know lambda functions yet :) I am looking into them right now ^^ Thanks a lot

Comment: @Gökay: `[](){...}` defines an anonymously-typed function object with no parameters, executing `...` when invoked. The closing `]` was a typo that I fixed later. In an attempt to reduce the number of nested parentheses, brackets, and braces, I have changed my answer to separate the creation of the lambda function from the call to the timer functions. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a solution that works without the need of variadic templates or lambdas (for which you will have to wait for the upcoming standard release), you can use `boost::bind` to make the function into one that takes no parameters by pre-binding all the parameters to the function:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Func>
int time_call(Func f) {
  int start_time = some_get_current_time(); //record the start time
  f(); // call the function with no parameters
  return some_get_current_time() - start_time; //return the time difference.
};

void my_algorithm(int x, float w, std::string s) {
  std::cout << x << w << s << std::endl;
};

int main() {
  int time_taken = time_call(boost::bind(&my_algorithm, 42, 0.3, "Hello World!"));
  std::cout << "The function took " << time_taken << " time-units to execute!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
};
```

The above will work on all compilers and doesn't require any of the features of C++0x. Note also, that in the call to `boost::bind`, you can place any variables (they don't have to be literal constants). And, also, `boost::bind` can work with pointer to member functions too.

EDIT: If you are wondering how `boost::bind` can accomplish this without variadic templates, well, it's simple, they just made one function template overload for all possible numbers of parameters (I think the default limit is 10 parameters, but it can be extended).

Comment: Ah, yes, I tend to forget about `boost::bind`! Lambda functions are so much easier to use and understand, but if you can't use them yet, then `bind` to the rescue! `+1` from me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, current C++ requires you to write a bunch of templates with varying lengths, one for each possible argument count. In principle, C++0x would allow you to use variadic templates like so:

```
template<typename Rv, typename Wrapper, typename... Args>
struct impl_wrapper {
    std::function<Rv (Args...)> func;

    Rv operator()(Args... args) const {
        Wrapper w;
        return func(args...);
    }

    impl_wrapper(const  std::function<Rv (Args...)> f)
        : func(f)
    {
    }
};

template<typename Wrapper>
struct wrap_func_ {
    template<typename Rv, typename... Args>
        impl_wrapper<Rv, Args...> operator()(const std::function<Rv (Args...)> &f)
        {
            return impl_wrapper<Rv, Wrapper, Args...>(f);
        }
};

template<typename Wrapper>
static wrap_func_<Wrapper> wrap_func;



struct test_wrapper {
    test_wrapper() {
        std::cout << "Begin call!\n";
    }

    ~test_wrapper() {
        std::cout << "End call!\n";
    }
};

int test_call(int x, char *y) {
    std::cout << y << x << std::endl;
    return x + 1;
}

int main() {
    std::function<int (int, char *)> f = test_call;
    f = wrap_func<test_wrapper>(f);

    std::cout << "Returned: " << f(42, "Prior to increment: ") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, this requires support for features not yet implemented in G++, nor, most likely, in any other extant C++ compiler:

```
test.cpp:21: sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand ‘Args ...’ into a fixed-length argument list
```

Therefore, you must instead use template overloading for each possible argument count, up to some reasonable maximum.